# Why do I get an "Attribute class is not allowed here" Error?

Tags: xml, attributes, phpstorm, sapui5, dtd

I am currently learning to develop SAP UI5 Apps with JetBrains PhpStorm. As there is no official UI5 plugin available for this IDE I did follow [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/22/configuring-jetbrains-webstorm-for-ui5-development/) guide to enable autocomplete and stuff like that by adding a OpenUI5 library and two schemas/DTDs to PhpStorm.

[image: added OpenUI5 lib]
[image: added the schemas/DTDs]

Now I've got the problem, that class attributes in XML items are marked red showing an error "Attribute class is not allowed here". This does only occur in XML-Files

This is my App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<App class="myAppDemoWT">
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}">
            <content>
                <Panel
                    headerText="{i18n>helloPanelTitle}"
                    class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
                    width="auto">
                    <content>
                        <Button
                            text="{i18n>showHelloButtonText}"
                            press="onShowHello"
                            class="myCustomButton"/>

                        <Input
                            value="{/name}"
                            description="Hello {/name}"
                            valueLiveUpdate="true"
                            width="60%"/>
                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

[image: errors]

Once I remove the added schemas / DTDs the errors disappear but autocomplete for UI5 features is unavailable again.
Executing the files works fine, also the class attributes take effect, so this is just an error caused by the IDE. Is there a way to solve this issue? Am I using the wrong .xsd files?

Thanks a lot in advance!